# Using/understanding Alarm manager force close [Android]

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-logcat, android-alarms

My android app keeps force closing, due to the recent addition of Alarm manager. I am new to alarm manager and did what i did with parts of tutorials. In the code i have said where i have put my 'doing code' (not sure if this is the right place?). Pls also mention where i should put other parts of my code, that are not affected be alarm manager.

Here is my logcat:

```
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127): Process: com.knight, PID: 1127
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.knight./com.knight.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:173)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at com.knight.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:44)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
04-16 14:36:52.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     ... 11 more
04-16 14:36:56.491: I/Process(1127): Sending signal. PID: 1127 SIG: 9
```

Here is my Alarm.java:

```
package com.knight.;

import java.util.Random;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Service;

public class Alarm extends Service{








    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        {
            //MY CODE????
    }

}



    private TextView findViewById(int textview3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the alarm setup java:

```
package com.knight.;

import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.knight..R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.class);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);



        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);



        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        alarmManager.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0, pendingIntent);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        // time set up is unsuccessful in earlier versions


    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }



}
```

Comment: You either have the wrong LogCat or the wrong `MainActivity` class. The `LogCat` shows that you are attempting to call `getSharedPreferences()` from an initializer in `MainActivity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have removed that part of the code from the MainActivity as it was there before i added in the alarm manager then was copied (and not removed) into the other java file

Comment: That's fine, but your LogCat stack trace is useless, because it is from code other than what you have now.

Comment: @CommonsWare give me a moment and i will try and update that